# DateTime.Parse changing date?

Tags: c#, datetime

This is my code snippet:

```
    public bool getEffDate()
    {
        testfunction(DateTime.Today.ToString("u"));
        return true; 
    }

    private bool testfunction(string modDate)
    {
        modDate = DateTime.Parse(modDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return true;
    }
```

DateTime.Today.ToString("u") - Returns current date 
Whereas, modDate returns current_date - 1..

Can someone help me with the UTC date function? Why is the Parse function bringing the previous day?

Comment: what timezone are you in?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
modDate = DateTime.Parse(modDate, null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I am assuming your timezone is Universal. You need to specify the timezone as per your requirements.